# Fake account listed as owner on my Facebook Page - How can I regain ownership?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Our writing group has a FB page  Have had it for years. Haven't checked page roles until recently when I went to add a new writer and found a different name as page owner Ruth M Dotie.  Got message owner Dotie must approve my request to add new person. So that person now controls who is on page. We still can post but what happens next. Ruth M Dotie name does not appear on Fbook or online so it's obviously fake. Filled out all complaints I could - concerned about theft of intellectual property. No response from Facebook. Tried right clicking name and ID listed - no account revealed.

Do not want page deleted but we are not technology savvy enough to figure out what to do next